# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve - Parsed request is a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, eslint, node-modules

I have class components based project (a requirement by company, can't change to function components)

Once I ran elint --fix and started the project again, it gives me this error **just for one file**.

Parsed request is a module
using description file: C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\shop\package.json (relative paist or is not a directory

C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\shop\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
looking for modules in C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\shop\node_modules

The file only contains an exported function that I use elsewhere to dispatch data. I'm not sure why it's looking in node_modules or how to fix this error.

The file looks something like this :

```
import store, { addToCart } from '../redux/store'

export function addToCartFunc (---props---) {

    ---code ---- 

  store.dispatch()
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this was happening, my guess it was recognizing the file as some kind of webpack but I fixed it by importing it as :

```
import { addToCartFunc } from './addToCartFunc.js'
```

instead of (like all others):

```
import { addToCartFunc } from './addToCartFunc'
```